# Find next word and replace in file

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have file which contains sentences:

```
File1.txt:
"I like Banana"
```

I want to find the word appears after "like" and replace it. I tried with string and works fine

```
String = "orange"
Text = 'I like Banana'
list_of_words = Text.split()
for u, word in enumerate(list_of_words):
    if 'like ' == word:
        next_word= list_of_words[u+ 1] 
        Text = Text.replace(next_word,String)
print(Text)
```

prints : `I like orange`

But when I apply it on file it only replace **(like)**:

```
with open(file, 'r') as open_file:
    read_file = open_file.readlines()
    output_lines = []

for line in read_file:
    words = line.split()
    output_line = []
    for u,word in  enumerate(words):
        if 'like' == word:
            new_word = words[u + 1] 
            word = word.replace(new_word,"Orange")
            output_line.append(word)
#--------------------------------------------------------

    output_lines.append(' '.join(output_line))
    with open(file, 'w') as open_file:
        open_file.write(' '.join(output_lines))
```

It replaces Like with orange:

```
I Orange Banana
```

Any idea why?!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if condition, you are confusing word with words. You replace being done on 'like', not ['I', 'like', 'bananas']. Since like does not contain 'oranges', that line is a no-op.

I think you want something more like this. Although this still needs to check boundaries (what if u + 1 is out of range?).

```
output_line = []
for line in read_file:
    words = line.split()
    for u,word in  enumerate(words):
        if 'like' == word:
            words[u + 1] = 'Orange'
    output_line.append(' '.join(words))
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file = 'File1.txt'
with open(file, 'r') as open_file:
    read_file = open_file.readlines()
    output_lines = []        

for line in read_file:
    words = line.split()
    for u, word in enumerate(words):
        if 'like' == word:
            words[u + 1] = 'Orange'
#--------------------------------------------------------

    output_lines.append(' '.join(words))
    with open(file, 'w') as open_file:
        open_file.write(' '.join(words))
```

I removed some of the unnecessary lists.